# Jailbreak app-mini browser

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweaks

What was the name of the jailbreak app/tweak that allowed you to open web pages in a popup web browser instead of going directly to safari? I remember it in iOS 7 but can't find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. Pro widgets comes with a mini browser. Not yet available for iOS eight.